# find the the limit points of this sequence..

Tags: real-analysis

Given $a_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ , consider the  sequence  {$a_n$} defined by

$ a_{n+1}  = \begin{cases} \frac{a_n}{2} &\text{ for  even n} ,\\ \frac{ 1+ a_n}{2} & \text  {for  odd n} \end{cases}$.

find the  the  limit points of this  sequence..

My attempt :  For  n odd  i get $ a_{n+1}= \frac{ 1+ a_n}{2}$
nad putting  $a_{n+1} =  {a_n}  = l$

Now  i get   $l= \frac{ 1+ l}{2}$ as  i get  $l =  1$  for odd..

as I don't  know  how to find the  $a_{n+1}$  when  n   will even

Pliz help me,,,,,

Comment: Hint: Look at the subsequences $a_{2k}$ and $a_{2k+1}$.

Comment: "Pliz help me,,,,," I don't think this is necessary, is it

Comment: im not  getting @ Dark,,,,can u elaborate more

Comment: Set $b_n = a_{2n+1}$ and $c_n = a_{2n}$. Derive the recurrence relations for $(b_n)_n$ and $(c_n)_n$, find their limits. Conclude.

Comment: thanks  u  clement

Comment: @ClementC.  i  have  deleted my copy and paste  answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$a_{n+1}  = \begin{cases} \frac{a_n}{2} &\text{ for  even n} ,\\ \frac{ a_n}{2}+\frac {1}{2} & \text  {for  odd n} \end{cases}$$

Let us start with $a_1=a$ and write a few terms to see the pattern.

$$ a, a/2, a/4+1/2, a/8+1/4 , a/{16}+5/8, a/{32}+5/{16}, a/{64}+21/32,...$$ It is clear that the parts including $a$ will tend to zero.

The remaining parts $$\{1/2,1/4,5/8,5/16,21/32,21/64,...\}$$
has two subsequences namely $$\{1/2 ,5/8,21/32,...\}$$ and  $$\{1/4 ,5/{16},21/64,...\}$$ The first subsequence is $$\{1/2 ,1/2+1/8,1/2+1/8+1/32,...\}$$ which converges to $2/3$

The second subsequence converges to half of the first limit which is $1/3$

Thus we have two limit points $$\{ 1/3,2/3\}$$